# How to pass my item from JSON to another page or class/component in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, class

I want to pass my data from one page to another but in an specific way.
I have a `json` brought via `AJAX` with this method (resp, error and result):

**myArrayItems**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../images/logo.png';
import '../App.css';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class myArrayItems extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
     fetch("https://myrestserver/myArrayItems")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(
        (result) => {
            console.log(result)
            this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
            });
        }
      )       
    }
```

And in my **View** i rendered like that with key.

```
                 <ul>
                    {items.map(item => (
                        <li key={item.title} className="list-group-item border-0">
                            <div className="wrapper">
                                <div className="myclass">
                                    <Link to={{ pathname: "/myitem/" }} className="App-link">
                                        <p className="text-left">{item.title}</p>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>

}

export default myArrayItems;
```

So I want to pass the `item.id`, `item.title`, `item.x` to the page *myitem*, but i imported the `myArrayItems` and still get `undefined`.

What I want to achieve is in my first class to display a list of items (What i did) but when i click on any of these items, to access them in the page *myitem*.

**myitem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../images/logo.png';
import '../App.css';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import myArrayItems from './myArrayItems';

const Background = {
  background: '#004272'
}



class myitem extends Component {

    render(){
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <header style={Background} className="text-center py-2 m-0">
                <img src={logo} className="img-fluid w-75"/>
              </header>
              <Container>
                <ul>
                    <p>{item.title}</p>
                </ul>
              </Container>
            </div>
          );
       }
    }

export default myitem;
```

I hope you can help me with that, thanks!

UPDATE: 
I'm creating a WebApp using ReactJS Library with "npx create-react-app".

Comment: It will be hard for anyone to help without knowing your approach to state management on this application.  Are you using Redux, context API, flux ect?

Comment: Sorry, im using native react, no redux or flux. I will update!!!